How to get an index of random property of array of objects?
I have an array of objects.
const items = [{
  name: "item1",
  img: "img/pic/picture1.png"
},
  name: "item2",
  img: "img/pic/picture2.png"
},
  name: "item3",
  img: "img/pic/picture3.png"
}];

I'm getting a random img property from it.
const randomImg =items[Math.floor(Math.random() *items.length)].img;
itemImg.src = `${randomImg}`;

I'd like to get a name property and assign it as alt. Could you direct me in which way I should do this?
I tried findIndex() method and indexOf(). But still got undefined or -1.
const altIndex = items.indexOf(randomImg);
itemImg.alt = items[altIndex].name;

//or
const altIndex = items.findIndex(ele => ele === randomImg[ele]);

Am I on the right way? Thank you in adavance and have a good day!

Any reason you just don't not store the random number that gets generated and use it whenever you need to access the information in the array?

Why pick a specific property of a random object to begin with, why not just the random object? const randomItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)], then you can access randomItem.img and randomItem.name afterwards.

Can't you just store the random item in a variable and use that, e.g., randomItem:


const items = [
  { name: "item1", img: "img/pic/picture1.png" },
  { name: "item2", img: "img/pic/picture2.png" },
  { name: "item3", img: "img/pic/picture3.png" }
];

const randomItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
console.log(`randomItem.name: ${randomItem.name}`);
console.log(`randomItem.img: ${randomItem.img}`);

// So you can do something like this now:
// itemImg.src = randomItem.img;
// itemImg.alt = randomItem.name;




My apologies, I somehow edited your answer by mistake (I intended to edit my own); I have rolled it back to your original version to undo my error. Please double-check to ensure that I haven't inadvertently messed anything up in the edit and rollback sequence. Sorry.

All good, no worries.

Thank you so much!Omg, how I can miss this one, the easiest way. Thank you one more time!

You can use object destructuring to make it short:


const items = [
  { name: "item1", img: "img/pic/picture1.png" },
  { name: "item2", img: "img/pic/picture2.png" },
  { name: "item3", img: "img/pic/picture3.png" }
];

const itemImg = {};
({name: itemImg.alt, img: itemImg.src} = items[Math.random() * items.length | 0]);
console.log(itemImg);




Cache the Object, and not its property and then retrieve both the name and src from that cached Object:


// your original Array of Objects had a syntax error as
// all Objects after the first were missing their
// opening '{' symbol:
const items = [{
  name: "item1",
  img: "//picsum.photos/id/10/200"
}, {
  name: "item2",
  img: "//picsum.photos/id/20/200"
},
{
  name: "item3",
  img: "//picsum.photos/id/30/200"
}];

// retrieving a random Object, rather than a single property of
// that Object, but otherwise using the exact same approach as in
// your original code, and then using destructuring
// assignment to simultaneously retrieve the two named properties
// ('img' and 'name') directly from the Object:
let {img, name} = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
    
// creating an <img> element, which implicitly exists in your
// own code, so use your own existing approach if that's
// better for your use-case:
let itemImg = document.createElement('img');

// assigning the retrieved properties to the HTMLImageElement
itemImg.alt = name;
itemImg.src = img;

// assuming that the 'name' property is descriptive of the
// <img>, I also added that text to 'title' attribute of
// the <img>:
itemImg.title = img;

// prepending the <img> to the document.body element:
document.body.prepend(
  itemImg
);




destructuring assignment.
document.createElement().
element.prepend().
HTMLImageElement.alt.
HTMLImageElement.src.
title attribute.
Math.floor().
Math.random().


Thank you! I really appreciate you answer. You helped a lot!

Ultimately, sure; but I was trying to strike a balance between OP's own code and some revisions. You do have a valid point, though. Edited to remove that variable.

Thanks, @Nick; I really was writing half-asleep today, wasn't I? Fixed, I'm frankly disappointed in myself that I let that through.

A slight adjustment should give you both the name and img properties. Instead of going for the img property, go for the item (random):


const items = [
    { name: "item1", img: "img/pic/picture1.png" },
    { name: "item2", img: "img/pic/picture2.png" },
    { name: "item3", img: "img/pic/picture3.png" }
];

const randomItem =items[Math.floor(Math.random() *items.length)];

const itemImg = document.querySelector('#randomImage'); //Placeholder
//with itemImg already defined ....
itemImg.src = randomItem.img
itemImg.alt = randomItem.name;
<img id="randomImage" width="55" alt="Default ALT">



